# openload.cc How can I extract encoding settings of videos?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, output

My customer needs streaming service for his IP cameras and he ask me about same output quality as videos in openload.cc but I can´t simulate similar quality.I tried several encoding combination but nothing works fine.

My client needs reduce quality/size with good visibility in output I ask my client about choice which online service has good visibility for him and he choose openload.cc

Sample is [here](http://openloadmovies.org) 480p (sorry about warez but I can´t find no warez content on openload

So I need find encoding settings now.
I try to save file and then use mediainfo but mediainfo did not detect full encoding settings (like CRF, one or two encoding pass, specific video bitrate - mediainfo detect only range of bitrate...)

I use ffmpeg as encoder so now I need to know which settings I need to use for same output quality as in [480p](http://openloadmovies.org) sample.

Thank you for help me.

Comment: Does the output from the IP camera look good or bad? Because if it already looks bad before you do anything with it then there is nothing you can do to improve the quality. What did you try? You should show your `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output.

Comment: Original video from cameras is good quality but Xvid codec is used so I use ffmpeg for live transcoding to AVC because Xvid can´t be streamed.

Comment: clarification:
AVC can use less bitrate with good visibility - for example:
Original IP camera video (Xvid) 40 minutes -> about 350MB
Openload video 480p (AVC) 40 minutes -> about 180MB

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it has been encoded with x264, download the file and run:

```
strings input | grep x264
```

It *may* output encoding information such as:

```
x264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - 
http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0
analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16
chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4
threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0
direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40
intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0
qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
```

**Do not copy and paste the displayed options and values**–instead [use the appropriate preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). Using the info above it is safe to assume the default settings were used (equivalent of using `-preset medium -crf 23`).

I'm assuming you're running Linux since you did not specify. If you're using Windows then `mediainfo` will likely also provide the same info if it is there.

Comment: The OP says, *mediainfo did not detect full encoding settings (like CRF,...*, so I'm guessing that the SEI was removed, if it was encoded with x264.

Comment: @Mulvya I read that but completely forgot it when writing the answer. The question is almost too broad to suggest much else; some short and easy to download samples could be helpful.